# How can I make image load faster from firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Loading images from firebase storage is very slow, it was taking more than `2sec` to show image in my web page. Is there any way to seed up image loading? Will it seed up when give read access to world Like: `allow read: if true`?

Please guide me, what is the best way to upload and download images from firebase storage? Thanks.

Following is my Storage Rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/test-project-faac7.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Code to get Download Url :

```
 this.storage.ref(item.imgQuestion).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
    item.imgQuestionUrl = url;
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `cloud-function` where the image can be compressed after `upload` and replace the original image. You can follow this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail) to get some idea. You will need to watch for `storage` upload to trigger your functions.