# Can I use firebase storage as a CDN?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to use firebase storage images on my website as a similar way of Content Delivery Network does. This web site is accessible/usable by a specific geographical location only.

In order to use firebase storage images, I need to convert it to downloadable URL first then use in `<img>`.

So, Is there any way I can directly use the firebase storage path in my site and Increase the loading speed of the images.

Thanks.

Following is my Firebase Storage Rule:

```
service firebase.storage {
   match /b/test-project-faac7.appspot.com/o {
     match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
```

}

Code is :

```
if (item.imgDesc) {
  this.storage.ref(item.imgDesc).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
    item.imgDescUrl = url;
  })
}
```

Comment: It looks like you asked a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584414/how-can-i-make-image-load-faster-from-firebase-storage

Comment: Yes, It is bit similar. Earlier one is about to increasing the loading speed of Image . But, here for content Delivery, content can be anything. (image, file, script, other data)